# use Joins for multiple tables in yii2

Tags: php, left-join, yii2

I am using yii2, I have 3 tables: posts, fans, comments and i want to use joinWith() to get the posts with their comments and the fan name (in fans table) for post and comments.
what i wrote is this query:

```
<pre>
 facebook_posts::find()->joinwith('fans')->joinWith('comments')->all();
</pre>
```

and I added these two functions for the relations:

```
<pre>
    public function getfans() {
        return $this->hasOne(Fans::className(), ['id' => 'from_id'])->from(fans::tableName() . ' FBF');
    }
    public function getComments() {
        return $this->hasMany(Comments::className(), ['parent_id' => 'id'])->from(comments::tableName() . ' FBC');
    }
</pre>
```

this gives me the posts and the data of the fan who wrote the post and its comments but what i need is the data of fan that wrote the comments also, so how can i join comments with fans table ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you have a `fan` relation in your `Comments` model, then you can use the following to get all comments for each post and the fan relation for each comment:

```
facebook_posts::find()->joinWith('fans')->joinWith(['comments', 'comments.fan'])->all();
```

Comment: Davey, what if you wanted to use one column of the 'comments' table or maybe the 'fans' table in the where() method, how would you do it?

Comment: @Murilo as follows: `->where(['comments.field1'=>'value1'])->all()` or `->where(['comments.fan.field1'=>'value1'])->all()`