# How to specify alias for multiple join with same table?

Tags: yii2

I have two relations defined in my Model to the same table

```
public function getCountry(){
    return $this->hasOne(Country::className(),['country_id' => 'country_id']);
}

public function getCurrency(){
    return $this->hasOne(Country::className(), ['country_id' => 'currency']);
}
```

I want to join both relation in my query. Below code is showing error.

```
Country::find()->joinWith(['country','currency'])->....
```

Tried this too

```
Country::find()->joinWith(['country','currency as cur'])->....
```

How to specify alias for the second relation ??

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606740/use-joins-for-multiple-tables-in-yii2

Comment: @InsaneSkull I gave alias while defining the relation like  $this->hasOne(Country::className(), ['country_id' => 'currency'])->from(Country::tableName() . ' cur');   But still getting Db Exception. Should i use the same alias while querying ?

Comment: so, db exception of query.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Thanks. Actually last change did solve the issue. An extra quote caused the Exception.

Comment: I am glad to help you.

Answer (score 10):

Since Yii 2.0.7:

```php
->joinWith(['country', 'currency cur'])... // Note we dont use `as`, just an space
```

Source: [Yii2 Guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#relation-table-aliases)

Answer (score 9):

You can give alias to particular relation as below :

```
->joinWith([
    'country', 
    'currency' => function ($q) {
        $q->from(Country::tableName() . ' cur');
    }
])
```

Refer this thread to get further details - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2377#issuecomment-34573765

Answer (score 3):

without relations

```
Category::find()
    ->select('c1.*')
    ->from('category c0')
    ->innerJoin('category as c1', 'c1.parent_id = c0.id')
    ->where(['c0.slug' => $parent]);
```